# Android - how to inflate a view with multiple EditText fields and read their values?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, inflate

For my Android application, I want to have a view which allows a user to click a plus button to add EditText fields, and next to the EditText fields, I want to have minus buttons that will remove them from the view. In essence, something that is very similar to adding multiple phone numbers/email addresses in the edit Contact interface on Android.

I imagine I will need to do this by inflating my main view with a separate one that contains the EditText and button I want to add each time. However, I have no idea how I will manage identifying each EditText and button with a unique ID, and thus, I have no idea how I would manage to grab the values of each EditText for saving to my database. Can someone advise me on what I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have inflated a sub-layout, then you should now have a `View` object.

You can then call `findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1)` on that `View` — assuming that you supplied IDs in the sub-layout XML.

So long as you keep track of each of the parent `View`s, you can always use `findViewById()` on them.  Or after inflation, if you really want you can set a new, globally-unique ID on each `EditText` using `setId()`.

Comment: What if I have in my sub-layout multiple EditTexts next to each other, wrapped in a RelativeLayout, and I have layout attributes such as "layout_below", "layout_toRightOf"? Would I have to modify these attributes when I change the IDs of all the EditTexts?

Comment: And is there no way I can set a string to be the element's ID? It seems absolutely counter-intuitive that "setId()" will only accept an int as an argument.

Comment: You can set a *reference* to a string as the ID, but not an arbitrary string defined at runtime. But again, I don't think it's necessary to change IDs. So long as you keep track of the parent Views, which presumably you need to do anyway, you don't need to re-set the IDs of any of its children.

Comment: Instead of using data member variables to store these elements (like I am with static EditTexts), I'm trying to store them in a data member multidimensional array of Objects (the row being each instance of the sub-layout, and the columns being each instance of the sub-layouts elements). Do you think this is a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a view widget dynamically, and generate your own ID as it is assigned.

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setId(myId);
```

Then you can refer back to that widget.

```
findViewById(myId);
```

Comment: Let's say that I want to follow [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299924/inflating-a-view-multiple-times-in-the-same-parent-when-a-button-is-clicked). The wrapper view has already been inflated with the sub-view when I click the add button. Now, how do I set the IDs of these new elements since, presumably, they have already been created by the inflater (thus making "Button b = new Button(this)" unnecessary)? Or how can I refer to them for data storage purposes?