# LayoutInflater to add multiple views

Tags: android, layout-inflater

For my app I have to dynamically create a number of horizontal linearlayouts with checkboxes and textviews. Currently I create these dynamically within a for loop. For performance and ease I thought using layoutinflater would be a better way to do this and thus define one horizontal linearlayout with the correct formatting then add these within some sort of a loop however I'm having trouble with this. I'm also open to if there are better ways to implement what I'm after (or if my current way is indeed better for performance etc.)

```
//my main layout
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
LayoutInflater inflate = getLayoutInflater();
//inflating the layout containing the horizontal
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.inflater, main, false);
//adding the view
main.addView(l);
```

Problem is I can't put this in a for loop of any kind. Below is the error log for repeating the addView command.

```
12-24 19:37:18.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test1/com.example.test1.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a 
parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I've also considered adding the layout to the main linearlayout and then getting it and duplicating it and then adding more. Could you guys possibly help me learn how to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why can't you put that in a loop of any kind?

Comment: Sorry, I've included my logcat.

Comment: What if you set the id of the linear layout in the loop, ie l.setId(i)

Comment: On an aside - it's usual to put comments *above* the line(s) of code you're commenting and not *below*.

Comment: @Asok, thank you though that still sadly throws the same error at the same place (the second time it tries to add the linearlayout).

Comment: Also check out this post, it may help.http://stackoverflow.com/q/4299924/1134705

Comment: @Asok, I had made sure layout orientation was the first thing I fixed because I've had that issue before :P But thank you ever so much!

Comment: this exact approach works fine for me on API 19. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.inflater, main, false);
```

I suspect the problem is you are specifying `main` as the `ViewGroup` parameter.

Try setting the `attachToRoot` parameter to `true` then remove the `main.addView(l)` line.

Alternatively set the `ViewGroup` parameter to `null` and keep the `main.addView(l)` line.

Comment: The first solution resulted in no error but only one view being added. The second worked perfectly! :D

Comment: @AndroidPenguin : Glad to help - I figured one of them would work but couldn't remember exactly as it's been a while since I did something like this.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple a solution, thought I must be completely off or something :P Really appreciate the help Squonk. :)